# Unable to suppress errors in valgrind

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

Can someone please show me an example of how to add custom suppressions to valgrind? I am 99.99% sure it generates an error for the string class and I want to suppress the errors in a .supp file. I thought it would be simple enough just adding it to the directory or just adding my function to the default.supp but the error is not suppress. This is what I did:

1) I Ran valgrind with `--gen-suppressions=yes`
2) Obtained the generated suppression for my error listed below

```
  #Custom Suppression
  {
     MyCustomSupression
     Memcheck:Addr1
     fun:strlen
     fun:_ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     obj:/home/steve/path/to/the/program
     fun:(below main)
```

}

3) I added the file to the directory where default.supp is located which is in my eclipse folder

4) I ran valgrind again but the error is still there

Note: I also tried adding the suppression to the default.supp file. Am I missing a step? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"I am 99.99% sure it generates an error for the string class"* Do you have a minimal example to demonstrate that? `std::string` should valgrind cleanly.

Comment: @BaummitAugen That probably depends on library, compiler, system and phase of moon. I have seen many std::string errors out of valgrind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to specify the suppression file when you run valgrind, like this

```
##Generate suppressions
valgrind --gen-suppressions=yes myProgram
## Cut-Paste into string.supp
##Now rerun valgrind
valgrind --suppressions=./string.supp myProgram
```

See [command line options](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.options) for more detail.

Comment: I have done this (sorry, meant to include that bit) but i get the error: "FATAL: can't open suppressions file "string.supp"

Comment: Did you specify the full path to the file? Please show the command you used.

Comment: You know, that was my issue. I thought if I put it in the same directory, i wouldn't have to command the full path, but now that I did, I found it. I marked your answer as correct, but you woudln't know how to make it so i wouldn't have to give the full path, would you? just something more simplified?

Comment: Put the suppression file in the directory where you are running valgrind from. Or in your home directory and use ~/string.supp.